# ES6 Module's importmap to Pug

Tags: pug

I am new in Pug. I try to translate this code to Pug v3.0.2:

```html
<body>
    <script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.3.6/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>

    <script type="importmap">
        {
            "imports": {
                "gl-matrix": "https://cdn.skypack.dev/gl-matrix@3.4.3"
            }
        }
    </script>

    <script type="module" src="js/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

I tried to make it:

```
    body
        script(async, src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.3.6/dist/es-module-shims.js")

        //- script(type="importmap").
        //-     !{console.log("hello world")}

        script(type="module", src="js/bundle.js")
```

This code prints "hello world" on server side, not on client side:

```
        script(type="importmap").
            !{console.log("hello world")}
```

Updated 7/5/2020

This code writes to console "hello" on the client side:

```
        script.
            console.log("hello")
```

But this code:

```
        script(type="importmap").
        {
            "imports": {
            "gl-matrix": "https://cdn.skypack.dev/gl-matrix@3.4.3"
            }
        }
```

generates this error:

```
Error: E:\_Projects\Games\silveira\snake-3d-silveira-websockets-webgl-js - pug\views\index.pug:14:9
    12| 
    13|         script(type="importmap").
  > 14|         {
----------------^
    15|             "imports": {
    16|             "gl-matrix": "https://cdn.skypack.dev/gl-matrix@3.4.3"
    17|             }

unexpected text "{
   "
    at makeError (E:\_Projects\node_modules\pug-error\index.js:34:13)
    at Lexer.error (E:\_Projects\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:62:15)
    at Lexer.fail (E:\_Projects\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:1629:10)
    at Lexer.advance (E:\_Projects\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:1694:12)
    at Lexer.callLexerFunction (E:\_Projects\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:1647:23)
    at Lexer.getTokens (E:\_Projects\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:1706:12)
    at lex (E:\_Projects\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:12:42)
    at Object.lex (E:\_Projects\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:104:9)
    at Function.loadString [as string] (E:\_Projects\node_modules\pug-load\index.js:53:24)
    at compileBody (E:\_Projects\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:82:18)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct usage of JS on client side is:

```
script.
  console.log("hello world")
```

The script in Pug:

```
script(type="importmap").
  {
    "imports": {
      "gl-matrix": "https://cdn.skypack.dev/gl-matrix@3.4.3"
    }
  }
```

Generated HTML:

```html
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
        "gl-matrix": "https://cdn.skypack.dev/gl-matrix@3.4.3"
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: hi! Could you write it in Pug, please: ```<script type="importmap">
        {
            "imports": {
                "gl-matrix": "https://cdn.skypack.dev/gl-matrix@3.4.3"
            }
        }
    </script>```

Comment: @8Observer8 see please the example in my answer above.  Used Pug v3.0.2.

Comment: This code generates the error: "unexpected text "{"". Please, see my updated question. I use Pug v3.0.2 too.

Comment: Your example above has't the indent under `script.`, the JSON block {} is on same level. It's your error.
Note: on next lines, after `script.` MUST BE the indent (2/4 spaces).